# Titanium: click on element(View, Label e.t.c.) should increase its top by 1

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I've binded the same function to all elements that I want(let's say View and Label).
In this onClick handler function I want to get the element which was clicked and increase its 'top' by 1.

Please tell me if you know how to do that, I can't find an answer yet.

My global click handler function:

```
function increaseElementTop(e) {
    // Here we should increase element's top position.
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get the e.source attribute from the Event e.  Then use the setTop() method.

```
if (e.source == $.yourLabel) {
    $.yourLabel.setTop($.yourLabel.getTop() + 1)
}
```

UPDATE: Regarding your comment: I thought it would only be used for two elements. A universal approach would be something like this:

```
e.source.setTop(e.source.getTop() + 1);
```

Unfortunately I have no machine available to test the code but I will do so later (Tuesday I guess). Just try it and let your programm print the `e.source` variable. If this does not work you can also try to use `e.source.getId()`.

Comment: I want to create universal click handler, which will handle any element.
So, I can't use "$.<my_element_id>". Is there any way to get element through event object which is retrieved as a parameter in handler function? There is some source.id object, but it's not clear how to get element from that.

Thanks, any more ideas?

Comment: I did, thank you. Can you elaborate on "e.source.getId()" thing please? Because, I've used "e.source.getTop()" and it didn't work(you can see my comment to other answer).

Comment: 'e.source.id' gives you the id of the element. Unfortunately in Titanium it is NOT possible to match the id with the real element attached to your view. So I was wrong suggesting it. As far as I can say it is therefore not possible to use an EventListener for every element without specifying the elements as my first piece of code suggests. I will think about another solution and update my post if I find something more elegant.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It doesn't seem like a complex thing, pretty strange that Titanium can't handle it.
Thank you, Robin.

Answer (score 1):

```
function increaseElementTop(e) {
    var theUIElement = e.source;
    theUIElement.top = theUIElement.top + 1;
}
```

Add the event listener to each of your UIElements, and this will get the element you click on & modify the top.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't work.

There is no e.source.top, although 'top' is specified for the element.
So, I can't get the top value.

I have tried it like this also:
var uiElement = e.source;
uiElement.top = uiElement.getTop() + 1;

But, it doesn't work also. Do you have any more ideas, Yozef?

Comment: See my answer for another try. You should use the setTop() method.

Comment: This should work. However, I am curious with the container that elements are in. If you hardcode the top of the elements, do they move downwards?

Comment: If I do something like "$.someElement.top = 20", element moves down.
If I do something like "theUIElement.top = 20", element doesn't move down.

Comment: Can you post a sample code of the element (and it's container)?